# DISM error 87 the add-package option is unknown

Tags: windows, windows-update, dism

I am attempting to manually install Windows update KB2999226. I have extracted the msu file, but when attempting to install the .cab file through dism, I get the following error.

[image: Error Message Screenshot]

Comment: Screenshot does not work.  Which is the reason your encourage to upload images to our imgur instead.

Comment: Screenshot should be working now.

Comment: [Your syntax is incorrect it is `Add-Package` not `add-package`...])https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd744559%28v=ws.10%29.aspx).  Determined this by doing a google search by the way.

Comment: @Ramhound Makes no difference. Cmd is not case sensitive.

Comment: Have you tried?  Those applets in my experience are case sensitive.  What version of Windows?

Comment: Yes I have tried. I'm on Windows 8.1

Comment: [Looking into it this has to do with your user profile.](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/d984f045-5b53-4640-9ba1-69be89e32239/dism-error-during-inject-software-updates?forum=winserversetup)

Answer (score 11):

Check "Windows Modules Installer" Service (TrustedInstaller.exe) is not disabled.
It solves my similar problem

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Could you improve your answer by explaining how/where to check if the service is disabled?

Comment: Burgi, how does it not? It just worked for me. DISM indeed shows this unrelated error when TrustedInstaller is disabled.

Comment: Run (win+r) services.msc and on my Windows 7 enabling "Windows Modules Installer" fixed this issue.

Answer (score 1):

DISM [global options](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh825079.aspx) are **NOT** case sensitive.

DISM [feature names](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh825265.aspx) **ARE** case sensitive.

[image]

---

I noticed you're doing this online.  Is there a particular reason you're using DISM instead of [WUSA](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/934307)?

```
wusa path\to\file.msu /quiet /norestart
```

---

Error 87 is indeed a parameter problem (verified by `net helpmsg 87` and confirmed [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms681382(VS.85).aspx)) but I'm not seeing specifically what's wrong with the syntax.

Did you copy/paste from the web or manually type it?  If the former, try the latter just to be sure it didn't use some strange em-dash type character.

I've never run into a case issue, except when dealing with FeatureNames, so this would be a first.  So to appease those who obsess over case (they likely come from a *n?x background ^_^) you could try doing it *exactly* as Microsoft has it documented and surround it on double quotes *just* to be sure:

```
DISM.exe /Online /Add-Package /PackagePath:"C:\tmp\tmp\Windows8.1-kb2999226-x64.cab"
```

Also, just to save us a bit of headache: You sure that's the proper path?

---

I'm on Windows 10 so the package doesn't apply to me but after pulling the .CAB from the .MSU, the command works just fine:
[image]

Try WUSA with the .MSU - you're making more work for yourself.

Comment: thx for very cool trick with: `net helpmsg 87`.

Comment: _No Windows commands are case-sensitive_, as Windows is a case-insensitive OS. Windows commands and parameters are often presented with the first letter of each word capitalized since it makes it easier for readers, similar to how the first character words within a hashtag is capitalized.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same on a 2012 R2 Server, just complete nondescript "parameter is incorrect" on installing .NET 4.6.2. Tried online, offline, DISM (error stating /Add-Package option unknown, as per the OP) and WUSA (error stating certificate invalid) with no luck.

In the end it turned out that the "Software Protection" service was disabled in Services. I enabled this service, and confirmed that the Windows Update service was enabled, and installation succeeded after that. This was on an Amazon EC2 instance, where I think the service was disabled in the AMI that I used to create the instance.

Answer (score 0):

The Problem is that you need a space  after 
"Remove-Package /packagename:Package_for_RollupFix~"BLA_BLA_BLA
So the quotes aren't literal here and the BLA_BLA_BLA are just whatever package you need to remove.  The big deal is that there is a space after the 
Remove-Package command and then a "/" and the command option (again the " is not a literal character to include, it is indicating exact characters within the confines of the quotation marks.  Windows should identify this as a syntax error  but those monkeys just have a generic option doesn't exist error instead.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem when tried to add language to a Win7PE which was created by WinBuilder, and the problem comes from this image, probably missing some files, and the problem was solved after changing some setting in WinBuilder, hope it can help someone when you download an optimized windows image.

Comment: `Dism` in Windows ≥8 isn't the same as `Dism` in Windows ≤7 - have you verified if you can use `Dism` from Windows ≥8 in Windows 7 _(I'm assuming you're not using Windows 7 since it's EoL)_?